# jQuery Mobile - dynamically created popups

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm populating an Updates History list in a jQuery Mobile app. I want to have key update data in the list, and more detailed data show when the user presses the Info tooltip. Screenshot from the app below, when it's working.

[image: Working properly after page refresh]

At the moment it only works properly after the page is refreshed - on receiving new data all the popups are visible, open (underneath the list), and there is no way to close them.

[image]

I'm assembling the HTML for each popup and adding to the DOM in a dedicated popups `<div>`. The injected HTML for each popup looks like

```
<div data-role="popup" id="updateInfo_0.04" class="ui-content updatesWidgetPopup" data-theme="b" data-position-to="window">...data in here..</div>
```

After a page refresh, everything works perfectly. The popups aren't visible and open/close properly when the tooltips are clicked. The DOM looks very different after jQuery mobile has worked its magic. Instead of the HTML I added, the popups `<div>` is now populated by placeholders

```
<div style="display: none;" id="updateInfo_0.04-placeholder">
    <!-- placeholder for updateInfo_0.04 -->
</div>
```

and the DOM now has a list of these appended

```
<div class="ui-screen-hidden ui-popup-screen ui-overlay-inherit" id="updateInfo_0.04-screen"></div>
<div class="ui-popup-container ui-popup-hidden ui-popup-truncate" id="updateInfo_0.04-popup">
    ... my HTML is now here in this inner div ...
</div>
```

I've tried `$("#popupsDiv").popup()` to see if that will correctly initialise things after the data is received, but it doesn't work. The only thing I can think of is manually creating the JQM HTML as above so it works without refreshing the page, but this doesn't seem right. Are popups not meant to be created dynamically like this?

Comment: instead of $("#popupsDiv").popup(), call popup() on the actual popups: $(".updatesWidgetPopup").popup(). Also, I asume each popup gets a unique ID, right?  If that does not help show us the code that creates the dynamic popups and tell us where it is called.

Comment: @ezanker That worked, thanks so much. Was just refactoring to use a click handler rather than injecting HTML, you've saved me a few hours work! Do you want to post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: You are welcome, I went ahead and posted it as an answer so future viewers can easily see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`$("#popupsDiv").popup()`

call popup() on the actual popups using the class updatesWidgetPopup that you assigned to all the popups:

`$(".updatesWidgetPopup").popup()`

This initializes the popup widget for each dynamically created popup.